# Fill in the empty lists in a list with value in python

Tags: python, list

Having the nested list like this:

```
lst = [[1,3], [], [2,2,4], [], [3,5]]
```

I'm trying to fill in the empty lists with a value (let's say 0). I know how can do it if we are flatting the list - so then we can use either list comprehension or some pandas solution, but how is it possible to do not to change the structure of nested list and just fill the values inside `lst`.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you not create a loop over `lst` and call `append` on the sublists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `i` you can directly access to `lst`. Since `i` is not a copy you can modify it and then see the result in the original list.

```
lst = [[1,3], [], [2,2,4], [], [3,5]]
for i in lst:
    if len(i) == 0:
        i.append(0)

Output:

[[1, 3], [0], [2, 2, 4], [0], [3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the list and use `append`.

```py
lst = [[1,3], [], [2,2,4], [], [3,5]]
for sub_lst in lst:
    if not sub_lst: # Check if sub_lst is empty
        sub_lst.append(0)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    if not l:
        lst[i] = [0]

print(lst)
# [[1, 3], [0], [2, 2, 4], [0], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: You can just `l.append(0)` instead of resetting `lst[i]` to a new list. That way you don't need the index